# Tensorflow tf.size not working with dynamic length tensor from tf.unique

Tags: python, tensorflow

This seems simple, but I've been stuck on it for a while. I have a list, and want to create a variable that's equal to the length of unique items in that list. A simple example looks like this:

```
def unique_zeros_tensor(arr):
  uniq_items, items_idxs = tf.unique(tf.constant(arr))
  return tf.Vector(tf.zeros([tf.size(uniq_items)]))
```

I get an error saying that inital value must have a shape specified.

I have also tried, `tf.shape`, `tf.zeros_like`, and even `tf.reduce_max(item_idxs)` all to no avail. I am able to do it by creating a session and running the results from tf.unique and using the values from there, but it feels like bad practice, but let me know if i'm wrong about that.

EDIT-
Adding shape to the constant didn't help,
using placeholder instead of tf.constant also didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Variables need to have their size essentially statically defined, before running the graph.

But things like tf.zeros etc are tensors, that dont really have values until you actually run the graph.

You either need to figure out a size to give your Variable that doesnt change, or rebuild the graph every time the size changes.

Edit: just to be clear ,the order of dependencies in tf is:

- first you build a graph. you dont need a session to build a graph. This is where you define the variable sizes, statically
- then you create one or more sessions from that graph. The variables in all of these sessions will have possibly different values, but all will have identical shapes/dimensions, since created from the same graph.

Comment: So to clarify, the way to do it is with sess.run

Comment: You  cannot change the size of a Variable inside the session. It is statically assigned within the graph.

Comment: So the tf.unique call isn't useful in the context that I'm using it? I should: sess.run(tf.unique(...)) and use the results in another graph?